# Is there any way to Forget signed-in account in AzureAD MSAL in swift ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, logout, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to logout the user and when i try to login back it takes the previous user credentials with out entering the password.
Is there any way to clear the credentials when user sign out in MSAL swift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let parameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(scopes: kScopes) parameters.promptType = MSALPromptType.login`

Keep the flag as `.login` so it will always ask the user to enter the credentials.

This is just the temp solution.

Comment: I have the same issue and I set MSALPromptType.login. but result is same, without login page callback to app with previous values

Comment: This solution doesn't work as of 2023.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for iOS 13 or below as well. By changing promptType enum, we can handle login behaviour in WebView.

```
 func acquireTokenInteractively() -> Single<(String, String)> {
            return Single<(String, String)>.create { [kScope] observer in
                guard let applicationContext = self.applicationContext else {
                    observer(.error(Errors.unknown))
                    return Disposables.create()
                }

                let parameters = MSALInteractiveTokenParameters(scopes: kScope, webviewParameters: MSALWebviewParameters(parentViewController: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!))
                parameters.promptType = .login //Change it based on ur requirement e.g. .selectAccount, .consent, .promptIfNecessary
                applicationContext.acquireToken(with: parameters) { (result, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        NSLoggerSwift.Logger.shared.log(.custom("OutlookLogin"), .error, "\u{274C} Could not acquire token: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        observer(.error(Errors.badToken))
                    }

                    guard let result = result else {
                        observer(.error(Errors.badToken))
                        return
                    }
                    observer(.success((result.accessToken, result.account.username ?? "")))
                }
                return Disposables.create()
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: On iOS it is not possible to do this as of 2019-05-30 due to limitations of the technologies selected.

You can read more at: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/589

And follow the feature request at: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/425

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
 parameters.promptType = .selectAccount
```

then the user can logout by clicking on ... and select logout

[image]